# Join table 1 to either column 1 or 2 from table 2 without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[MS SQL 2008]

I have tables (all columns are string names):
A: two columns relating some datafield to an owning entity
B: three columns defining a hierarchy of entities

I need to create a singe table of the whole hierarchy (including all rows not existing in both tables), but the key column in table A (shown as Acol2) can be in either column 1 or 2 of table B...

```
A:                         B:
 Acol1 | Acol2                Bcol1 | Bcol2 | Bcol3
-------+------              --------+-------+------
   A   |   B                    B   |   X   |   Y
   C   |   D                    Q   |   X   |   Y
   E   |   F                    H   |   D   |   Z
   G   |   H                    W   |   V   |   U
```

The output should be

```
Hierarchy:
 Acol1 | Bcol1 | Bcol2 | Bcol3
-------+-------+-------+------
   A   |   B   |   X   |  Y
  Null |   Q   |   X   |  Y
   C   |  Null |   D   |  Z
   G   |   H   |   D   |  Z
   E   |  Null |  Null | Null
  Null |   W   |   V   |  U 

Logic (also added to original):
    If A has no record in B, show A with all Null
    If A has record in Bcol1, show A with full row B
    If A has record in Bcol2, show A with Null, Bcol2, Bcol3
    If B has no record in A, show B with Null for Acol1
```

I have tried all sorts of UNIONs of two separate JOINs, but can't seem to get rid of extraneous rows...

1. `B LEFT JOIN A ON Acol2=Bcol1 UNION B LEFT JOIN A ON Acol2=Bcol2;` 
   gives duplicate rows, as the second part of the union has to set Bcol1 to NULL
   (perhaps one solution is a way to remove this duplicate NULL row?)
2. `B INNER JOIN A ON Acol2=Bcol1 UNION B INNER JOIN A ON Acol2=Bcol2;`
   Obviously removes all the rows from A and B that have no shared keys
   (solution as to easy way to regain just those rows?)

Any idea appreciated!

To play:
[SQL removed - see fiddle in reply comments]

Comment: can you create a sql fiddle for us?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
  Table1.ACol1,
  CASE WHEN Table1.ACol1 = Table2.BCol1 THEN Table2.BCol1 ELSE NULL END AS BCol1
  Table2.BCol2,
  Table2.BCol3
FROM
  Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Table2
    ON Table1.ACol2 IN (Table2.BCol1, Table2.BCol2)
```

When you say `no duplicates`, this is only possible if `ACol2` only ever appears in one field of one row in Table2.  If it appears in multiple places, you'll get duplication.
  - If that's possible, how would you want to chose which record from Table2?

Also, in general, however, this is a SQL-Anti-Pattern.

This is because the join would prefer an index on Table2.  But, since you never know which field you're joining on, no single index will ever satsify the join condition.

**EDIT**:

What would make this significantly faster is to create a normalised TableB...

```
 B_ID | B_Col | B_Val
------+-------+-------
   1  |   1   |   B
   1  |   2   |   X
   1  |   3   |   Y
   2  |   1   |   Q
   2  |   2   |   X
   2  |   3   |   Y
   3  |   1   |   H
   3  |   2   |   D
   3  |   3   |   Z
   4  |   1   |   W
   4  |   2   |   V
   4  |   3   |   U
```

Then index that table with `(B_ID)` and on `(B_Val)`...

Then include the `B_ID` field in the non_normalised table...

```
  ID  | Bcol1 | Bcol2 | Bcol3
------+-------+-------+-------
  1   |   B   |   X   |   Y
  2   |   Q   |   X   |   Y
  3   |   H   |   D   |   Z
  4   |   W   |   V   |   U
```

Then use the following query...

```
SELECT
  Table1.ACol1,
  CASE WHEN Table1.ACol1 = Table2.BCol1 THEN Table2.BCol1 ELSE NULL END AS BCol1
  Table2.BCol2,
  Table2.BCol3
FROM
  (
    Table1
  LEFT JOIN
    Table2Normalised
      ON  Table2Normalised.B_Val = Table1.ACol2
      AND Table2Normalised.B_Col IN (1,2)
  )
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Table2
    ON Table2Normalised.B_ID = Table2.ID
```

**EDIT:**

Without changing the schema, and instead having one index on BCol1 and a second index on Bcol2...

```
  SELECT ACol1, BCol1, BCol2, BCol3 FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.ACol2 = b.BCol1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ACol1, NULL,  BCol2, BCol3 FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.ACol2 = b.BCol2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ACol1, NULL,  NULL,  NULL  FROM Table1 a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE BCol1 = a.ACol2)
                                                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE BCol2 = a.ACol2)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,  BCol1, BCol2, BCol3 FROM Table2 b WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ACol2 = b.BCol1)
                                                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ACol2 = b.BCol2)
```

But that's pretty messy...

Comment: how grossly inefficient is that?

Comment: @Woot4Moo - I agree, but I didn't design either the schema or the functional requirement.

Comment: True, just waiting on OP to give us a fiddle

Comment: @Woot4Moo - I did it for him :-)

Comment: Didn't know of fiddle - useful thing learned from this if nothing else!

Comment: @Dems - I didn't create the original, just trying to work with it!  Logic says that dataset C has been created from the point in the hierarchy D, hence there was no "Bcol1" ever in history; whereas G was acquired from H, which was created as a sub-entity to D (i.e. H).

Comment: @Pythonist - If TableA had an entry `J, U` would that map to `NULL, NULL, U`? What I mean to ask is, can you be very specific about the exact rules as to when to join, and what to display? :)

Comment: @Dems - as per E/F, it maps to E, Null, Null, Null.

Comment: Logic (also added to original):
    If A has no record in B, show A with all Null
    If A has record in Bcol1, show A with full row B
    If A has record in Bcol2, show A with Null, Bcol2, Bcol3
    If B has no record in A, show B with Null for Acol1

Comment: @Pythonist - What about the current edit?  How does that match what you expect to happen?

Comment: @Dems - I see what you're doing there, but the only way I can implement that is to create the indexed from the non-indexed (versus the sensible way you describe) due to lack of design control on table B.  I will play with this, though.

Comment: @Pythonist - One final alternative added.